# how do can I show matrix values line per line

Tags: java, matrix

I have a matrix : 5x15 :

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
for(int j=0;j<15;j++){
String[][] Matrix = { { "0", "0", "", "0", "5", "6", "", "", "55", "", "", "", "", "" }, { "1723", "0", "", "0", "0", "3", "", "", "2", "", "", "", "", "" },
        { "10", "0", "", "0", "0", "0", "", "", "0", "", "", "", "", "" }, { "69", "0", "", "0", "0", "20", "", "", "100", "", "", "", "", "" },
        { "35", "0", "", "0", "15", "20", "", "", "57", "", "", "", "", "" } };
system.out.println(Matrix);
}}
```

and I need to print each line : line1,line2,..line5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `system.out.println(Matrix);` and add at the end (outside the two loops):

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i) {
  System.out.println(Arrays.asList(matrix[i]));
}
```

Arrays are not printed readable, but collections like List are.

PS: by convention, variables start with lowercase, types and constants with uppercase

Comment: so I don't need to declare j ?

Comment: @lamisse: no, neither i, remove the twoo loops around matrix = ... and just add the code above at the end

Answer (score 2):

```
final String[][] matrix = { { "0", "0", "", "0", "5", "6", "", "", "55", "", "", "", "", "" },
        { "1723", "0", "", "0", "0", "3", "", "", "2", "", "", "", "", "" },
        { "10", "0", "", "0", "0", "0", "", "", "0", "", "", "", "", "" },
        { "69", "0", "", "0", "0", "20", "", "", "100", "", "", "", "", "" },
        { "35", "0", "", "0", "15", "20", "", "", "57", "", "", "", "", "" } };

for (String[] row : matrix) {
    System.out.println((Arrays.toString(row)));
}
```

Will produce the following output:

```
[0, 0, , 0, 5, 6, , , 55, , , , , ]
[1723, 0, , 0, 0, 3, , , 2, , , , , ]
[10, 0, , 0, 0, 0, , , 0, , , , , ]
[69, 0, , 0, 0, 20, , , 100, , , , , ]
[35, 0, , 0, 15, 20, , , 57, , , , , ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
for (String[] row : matrix)
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
```

To fix **your code** I suggest you move out the matrix declaration out of the loop, and add a print / println like this:

```
String[][] Matrix = {
        { "0", "0", "", "0", "5", "6", "", "", "55", "", "", "", "", "" },
        { "17", "0", "", "0", "0", "3", "", "", "2", "", "", "", "", "" },
        { "10", "0", "", "0", "0", "0", "", "", "0", "", "", "", "", "" },
        { "69", "0", "", "0", "0", "20", "", "", "10", "", "", "", "", "" },
        { "35", "0", "", "0", "15", "20", "", "", "57", "", "", "", "", "" }
};

for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<14;j++){
        if (j > 0)
            System.out.print(", ");

        System.out.printf("%2s", Matrix[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

**Output:**

```
 0,  0,   ,  0,  5,  6,   ,   , 55,   ,   ,   ,   ,   
17,  0,   ,  0,  0,  3,   ,   ,  2,   ,   ,   ,   ,   
10,  0,   ,  0,  0,  0,   ,   ,  0,   ,   ,   ,   ,   
69,  0,   ,  0,  0, 20,   ,   , 10,   ,   ,   ,   ,   
35,  0,   ,  0, 15, 20,   ,   , 57,   ,   ,   ,   ,
```